# Creating signature in Java with existing public key

Tags: android

I want to access the Box API and authorize using a JWT (Json Web Token). To do so, I need to create a Assertion:
"Every JWT assertion is composed of three components, the header, the claims, and the signature.

- The header specifies the algorithm used for the JWT signature.
- The claims contain the information necessary to authenticate and provide the correct token.
- The signature is used to verify the identify of the application and is verified using the public key.2

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You question seems too board. I suggest you to read [ask]. Can you show what you tried and explain where you are stuck?